# How to create multiple new ellipsi at the mouse location (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, loops, ellipse

I want to basically create a form of paint.net in the browser. Here's the code I have so far; However it does everything except for draw, I want to be able to hold down left click and make the area where the ellipse is become painted, can anyone help me with this?

```
var mx = 0;
var my = 0;
var mw = 10;
var mss;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth-18, windowHeight-18);
    noCursor();
}
function draw() {
    background(200);
    mx = mouseX;
    my = mouseY;
    noFill();
    ellipse(mx, my, mw, mw);
    mss = mw.toString()/200;
    textSize(10);
    fill(0);
    text(mss, 3, 12);
    text("Scroll to Change Pen Size", 3, height-5);
}
function mouseWheel() {
    if (mw >= 200) {
        mw = 10;
    } else {
        mw = mw + 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify "It does everything except for draw"? What do you want to accomplish? On my browser I see a circle moving around following my mouse-cursor.

Comment: I just did, thank you for helping me explain my issue better

Comment: You need a `mouseDragged()` function where you draw the circle. You need to draw the background in `setup()` so you don't overdraw anything. I was able to achieve what you want, but unfortunately it wasn't possible to still draw the circle moving around when it's not pressed, because you're not drawing the background anymore...